# path in wix script

Tags: wix, wix3.6

The Wix script is in C drive.
In the script I have

```
<File Id='asmx' Name='file1.asmx' DiskId='1' Source='..\folder1\folder2\file1.asmx' />
```

In which Drive it will look for this file.
Actually the file is present in my D: drive.

Comment: You should get acquainted with this article before going further: http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/specifying_source_files.htm

Answer (score 1):

> Source='..\folder1\folder2\file1.asmx' />

`..\` tells that go one step up. So it will go up one folder from your `project directory` and search in `\folder1\folder2`

Answer (score 0):

All depends on what you specify for

Directory Id="TARGETDIR"

The article mentioned in the above comment is the way to go. Read through that.